# I can't scale my key frames correctly

Tags: animation, keyframes

[image]I am trying to animate a character. I am following a tutorial by David Andrade as I'm new to Blender

Currently there are 10 key frames, 1 key frame per frame. I wanted to change the timing of the animation so I moved my play head to frame 1, selected all key frames by clicking <kbd>A</kbd> , then clicked <kbd>S</kbd>, then moved my mouse so I can scale my key frames to around 250 frames.

The problem is that when I am scaling, other new key frames seem to appear in between and the timing is not how I want it. I'm using blender 2.79.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've fixed the issue by trial and error. I first selected all the controls (I think that's what they are called) on the character by clicking on an empty area, then clicking a twice.That made them all highlighted with their colors. Then I went to the dope sheet and did what I did previously to the key frames and . . . Voila :) I know that was a crappy explanation but hey it worked!!!

Thanks!